# How to display the updated score in Kivy Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I want to display the updated score value but only the initial value is displayed.
The score variable in the MainClass() is linked to the kivy file, but the score is not updating. It is always showing 0 whereas it should add 1 whenever the player wins the game.
Any solution will be very helpful.
Thank You.

main.py

```
...some code...
class MainClass(Widget):

score = NumericProperty(1)
score = 0

pattern_maker(score) # This is the function to make the pattern.
once_pattern_shown = False

won_lost = ""

checked = False

def update(self, dt):
    global button_clicked, pattern_in_count, pattern, check_ans_clicked

    start_obj = Start()

    if start_pattern_show and not self.once_pattern_shown:
        for i in range(0, self.score+1):
            if pattern[i] == 'r':
                beep1.play()
                self.once_pattern_shown = True
            elif pattern[i] == 'g':
                beep2.play()
                self.once_pattern_shown = True
            elif pattern[i] == 'b':
                beep3.play()
                self.once_pattern_shown = True
            elif pattern[i] == 'y':
                beep4.play()
                self.once_pattern_shown = True

    if start_pattern_in and check_ans_clicked and pattern_in_count <= self.score+1:
        if button_clicked == pattern:
            self.won_lost = "won"
        else:
            self.won_lost = "lost"
    elif start_pattern_in and check_ans_clicked and pattern_in_count > self.score+1:
        print "No more button clicks are allowed."
    elif start_pattern_in and check_ans_clicked:
        print "Misfunction."

    if button_clicked == pattern and not self.checked:
        self.score += 1 # I want this score to be displayed.
        self.checked = True

class Test2App(App):

def build(self):
    game = MainClass()
    Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 2) # call 'update' func every 1.0s.
    return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test2App().run()
```

test2.kv

```
...some code...
<MainClass>:

canvas: 
    Color:
        rgb: 0, 55, 55
    Rectangle: 
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.width, root.height

Label:
    pos: 10, root.height-70
    font_size: 25
    text: "SCORE: " + str(root.score)
...some more code...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your label from Python code inside your `update` method.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty 
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string('''
<MainClass>:
    Label:
        id: label
        pos: 10, root.height-70
        font_size: 25
        text: "SCORE: 0"
''')

class MainClass(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(1)
    score = 0

    def update(self, *args):
        self.score += 1
        self.ids['label'].text = "SCORE: " + str(self.score)

class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):
        game = MainClass()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1) # call 'update' func every 1.0s.
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test2App().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for giving a solution. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the line `score = 0`, by doing this`score` stops being an instance of `NumericProperty` class to become an `int` instance, and therefore it stops generating events when it is modified.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


Builder.load_string('''
<MainWindow>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        id: lb_score
        text: "Score " + str(root.score)
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: "+1"
        on_press: root.add_score()

''')


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def add_score(self):
        self.score += 1

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks man. It really worked, and your explanation is really good. Thanks.